# Me muestra varias veces el nombre de cada columna

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hola camaradas tengo una consulta fijense que quiero mostrar datos de mysql en una tabla (código HTML) en php pero a la hora de mostrar me muestra despues de cada registro el nombre de la columna. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que solo me muestre una vez el nombre de la columna?

```html
    <?php foreach($resultado as $dato): ?>
    <table class="table" >
    <table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Código Personal</th>
      <th scope="col">Nombre Producto</th>
      <th scope="col">Cantidad</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  
            <td><?php echo $dato['id_entrada'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $dato['cod_personal'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $dato['nombre_producto'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $dato['cantidad'] ?></td>
  </tbody>
</table>

        <?php endforeach ?>
```

Este es el código para mostrar los datos

```html
<?php

include_once 'conexion.php';
$sql_leer = 'SELECT * FROM entradas';

$gsent = $pdo->prepare($sql_leer);
$gsent->execute();

$resultado = $gsent->fetchAll();

//var_dump($resultado);//

?>
```

El de la conexión es este:

```html
<?php

$link= 'mysql:host=localhost:; dbname=inventario';
$usuario = '';
$pass = '';

try{
    $pdo = new PDO($link,$usuario,$pass);

    //echo 'conectado';//

} catch (PDOException $e){
    print "¡Error!:" . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

Y este es el error:
[image: Les adjunto el error]

Answer (score 3):

1. Eso ocurre por que estas metiendo la declaración del encabezado de tu tabla dentro del mismo ciclo `foreach` por eso en cada iteración que obtiene resultados vuelve a generar el nombre de la columna, trata con el código del modo siguiente.
2. Además veo que tienes doble vez declarado esto `<table class="table">` lo cual veo innecesario entonces habría que quitarlo también
3. Del mismo modo la etiqueta `<tbody></tbody>` va por dentro del bucle `foreach`

**CÓDIGO**

```
<table class="table" >
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Código Personal</th>
      <th scope="col">Nombre Producto</th>
      <th scope="col">Cantidad</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
 <?php foreach($resultado as $dato): ?>
         <tbody>
            <td><?php echo $dato['id_entrada'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $dato['cod_personal'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $dato['nombre_producto'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $dato['cantidad'] ?></td>
          </tbody>
<?php endforeach ?>
</table>
```